# Is Node.js required by Cypress in order to get full functionality?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I'm reading the Cypress website and I am getting a bit confused about its relationship with Node.js

Cypress documentation clearly states that certain commands, such as cy.task(), cy.request(), are executed in Node, which indicates it is required.
However, [the documentation also says](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#Direct-download):
"If you’re not using Node or npm in your project or you want to try Cypress out quickly, you can always download Cypress directly from our CDN."

Does this mean that without installing Node you can still use Cypress with the exception of above mentioned commands? Or does Cypress executable actually contain some version of Node baked in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no --- it's not required when you run Cypress from a binary.

Cypress runs on [Electron](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/about?q=node), which bundles Node.js in.

As for `cy.task` etc., it communicates with Cypress' own background node.js process (from Electron), not one that would be supplied by host (your) environment.